# Receive function in python, how to link

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

When I click on the send button in the console, it is displayed that I am connected and my nickname, but my text (input) in the chat is not displayed in the GUI, instead the word "Error" from the receive() function is displayed in the console.
And sometimes it displays an error with :

```
message = self.sock.recv(1024)
```

Here is the code itself from the client and server files:

Server.py

```
def receive():
    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f"Connected with {str(address)} !")
        nickname = client.recv(1024)
        users.append(nickname)
        clients.append(client)
        client.send(f"Connected to the server\n".encode('utf-8'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle, args=(client,))
        thread.start()
print("server running..")

receive()
```

Client.py

```
def receive(self):
    while self.running:
        try:
            message = self.sock.recv(1024)
            if message == 'NICK':
                self.sock.send(self.username.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                if self.gui_done:
                    self.chatarea.config(state='normal')
                    self.chatarea.insert('end', message)
                    self.chatarea.yview('end')
                    self.chatarea.config(state='disabled')
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
            break
        except:
            print("Error")
            self.sock.close()
            break
```

Comment: Print the actual error so you know the reason.

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\server.py", line 44, in <module>
    receive()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\server.py", line 36, in receive
    nickname = client.recv(1024)

Comment: Put the traceback in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Get rid of the `except:` block. It's hiding the detailed error message, so there's no way to tell why it's failing.

Comment: it swears at a variable that stores bytes (messages from users) by message = self.sock.recv(1024). My chat window for displaying messages from users consists of lineEdit. Can I change lineEdit to something else that it has taken byte values ?

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\clients.py", line 249, in receive
    self.chatarea.insert(message)
TypeError: insert(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bytes'

Comment: `message = self.sock.recv(1024).decode()`

Comment: Now when you click on the send button, the window simply closes and such an error occurs on the file console server.py :
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\server.py ", line 36, in receive
    nickname = client.recv(1024)
I understand it is also necessary to decode this client? But such a function is not available for her

Comment: `nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: The program behaves very strangely. At the first launch, after correcting the code and clicking on the "send" button, the message "connected to the server" was displayed in the chat window, as it should have been, but then when entering the message and pressing the "send" button, the program simply closed without issuing any errors in the console. Further, on the 2nd attempt, when pressing the button, it immediately closed, this time the message "connected to the server" did not appear

Comment: File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\server.py", line 45, in <module>
    receive()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\HMessageRemake\server.py", line 37, in receive
    nickname = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

Comment: There could be issues in the `handle` function.

Comment: https://replit.com/@Noname989/Serverpy?v=1
it's my server.py file code